# Is there a way to loop through elements in c# wpf and connect them to a MySQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, wpf, loops

I'm making a kind of a webshop in c#. So I have this UI (see picture) and I want to bind the data to the UI elements with a loop (less code). I can do this manual with a lot of code but that's not what I want. I was thinking about element looping but I can't find anything about that.
Does anyone know how to do this?
[image: Picture UI]

Comment: Since there is no code or xaml in this question, im guessing you want suggestions. My suggestion is you dont be afraid of writing code, and use the MVVM pattern and bind the way that is the most common. This will give you the most experience and a flexible app in the process, where future changes are a lot easier

Comment: "I want to bind the data to the UI elements with a loop" you don't even need a loop. just use `ItemsControl`

Comment: Basically, your picture looks like `ListBox` + `WrapPanel` + `ItemTemplate`. But the question as it stated is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirement, I would like to suggest you to follow MVVM, as also suggested in comments. Here are following steps to achieve your goal.

1. Define your model, which contains all required properties like Picture, Ids, Title, description etc.
2. Define ViewModel which contains ObservalbeCollection or List(based on your requirement) of model.
3. Fill your Collection from DB, by any ORM you like.
4. You need to beautify UI to display List of items. I would suggest you to use List view and define (ItemTemplate, ItemContainerStyle and ItemPanel).
5. Bind listview with VM's Property (Collection of your model).
   Thats all

Note: In each item you have button. When you set items source to listview, by default it will look command in related Model. If you want to define common Command for all items button, you need to create Command in VM, and bind this command to listview itemtemplate Button by using RelativeSource and  finding Ancestor, so that search VM's Command in ancestor datacontext.

Answer (score 0):

Define product model:

```
public sealed class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

Define service to load products from database:

```
public sealed class ProductsService
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> LoadProductsAsync()
    {
        // TODO: to load products from database use your favorite ORM
        // or raw ADO .NET; anyway, you want this to be async
        // since this is I/O bound operation
    }
}
```

Define product view model. It just wraps model and provides "Add to cart" command:

```
public sealed class ProductVm : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly Product model;
    private readonly Lazy<ImageSource> image;

    public ProductVm(Product model)
    {
        this.model = model;

        // we need to load image just once, hence here comes Lazy<T>
        image = new Lazy<ImageSource>(LoadImage);

        // TODO: add command initialization here;
        // usually you want DelegateCommand/RelayCommand/etc
        // AddToCartCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddToCart);
    }

    public string Name => model.Name;

    public string Description => model.Description;

    public ImageSource Image => image.Value;

    public ICommand AddToCartCommand { get; }

    private ImageSource LoadImage()
    {
        if (model.Image == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var image = new BitmapImage();

        using (var mem = new MemoryStream(model.Image))
        {
            image.BeginInit();
            image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.UriSource = null;
            image.StreamSource = mem;
            image.EndInit();
        }

        image.Freeze();

        return image;
    }
}
```

Define main window view model:

```
public sealed class MainWindowVm
{
    private readonly ProductsService productsService;
    private ObservableCollection<ProductVm> products;

    public MainWindowVm()
    {
        // in production apps, services must be injected using DI-containers
        // like Autofac, MEF, NInject, etc
        productsService = new ProductsService();
    }

    public IEnumerable<ProductVm> Products
    {
        get
        {
            if (products == null)
            {
                // when UI wants to display products,
                // we create empty collection and initiate async operation;
                // later, when async operation will be finished,
                // we will populate collection using values from database
                products = new ObservableCollection<ProductVm>();

                var _ = LoadProductsAsync();
            }

            return products;
        }
    }

    private async Task LoadProductsAsync()
    {
        // service returns collection of product models,
        // but we need collection of product view models
        var productModels = await productsService.LoadProductsAsync();

        foreach (var model in productModels)
        {
            products.Add(new ProductVm(model));
        }
    }
}
```

Define a view. You need an `ItemsControl`, `ItemTemplate` and `WrapPanel`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVm />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProductVm}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Width="48" Height="48" Source="{Binding Image}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="Add to cart" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding AddToCartCommand}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image]

Sample project is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lajQA3JO0ClsENgFKg3ExXQgAWCFdFer).